# Spectrum of unitary transform

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T: \operatorname{dom}(T) \rightarrow H$ be self-adjoint, then $U(T):=(T+i)(T-i)^{-1}$ is defined and unitary( this is clear to me). Furthermore, we have that $\sigma(U(T)):= \overline{\{ t; \exists y \in \sigma(T): t = \frac{y+i}{y-i}\}}$, i.e. $1 \notin \sigma(U(T)).$ I guess that there is a nice trick to show this that I currently just don't see. I hope that anybody here knows how to do this.

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the brute force approach:
$$
\begin{align}
     (T+iI)(T-iI)^{-1}-\lambda I & = (T+iI)(T-iI)^{-1}-\lambda(T-iI)(T-iI)^{-1} \\
    & = (T+iI-\lambda T+\lambda iI)(T-iI)^{-1} \\
    & = ((1-\lambda)T+i(1+\lambda)I)(T-iI)^{-1} \\
    & = (1-\lambda)(T+i\frac{1+\lambda}{1-\lambda})(T-iI)^{-1}
\end{align}
$$
The above is invertible iff $-i(1+\lambda)/(1-\lambda) \notin\sigma(T)$. If $\mu \in \sigma(T)$, then
$$
      -i\frac{1+\lambda}{1-\lambda} = \mu \iff \lambda = \frac{\mu+i}{\mu-i}.
$$
There is a special case to be considered, but I'll leave that.